# MongoDb query for getting count information after aggregation for more than one size from collecgtion

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

What i am try to achieve is getting more than one size from collection.below query not working as expected.

shown below is collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59e9c029c817c359508b4568"),
"client_id" : "20",
"device_details" : {
    "type" : "others",
    "name" : "Google Bot",
    "os" : null,
    "os_version" : null,
    "browser" : null,
    "browser_version" : null,
    "user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
    "width" : NumberLong("1024"),
    "height" : NumberLong("1024"),
    "fingerid" : "c714d8f7eb7d216693c0ddd06cfc0940",
    "canvasfingerid" : "84f1922a78572180c7f29f938486c1db",
    "webglfingerid" : "24700f9f1986800ab4fcc880530dd0ed",
    "hardwarefingerid" : "431171c98112e1f0dfb3b40f617111f9",
    "platformos" : "Linux x86_64",
    "adblock" : "false",
    "donot" : "unknown",
    "liedlanguage" : "false",
    "liedos" : "false",
    "liedbrowser" : "false",
    "ratio" : NumberLong("1"),
    "depth" : NumberLong("24"),
    "language" : "en-US",
    "liedresolution" : "false",
    "timezoneoffset" : "420",
    "regularplugin" : "No plugins found",
    "localstorage" : "true",
    "sessionstorage" : "true",
    "touchsupport" : "false",
    "canvas" : "Tracked",
    "webgl" : "Unknown",
    "hardwareconc" : "8",
    "referrer" : null,
    "referrer_url" : null,
    "scrorientation" : "landscape-primary"
},
"ip_list" : [
    "66.249.66.146",
    "66.249.66.21"
],
"ip_details" : [
    {
        "ip_address" : "66.249.66.146",
        "latitude" : 37.41919999999999,
        "longitude" : -122.0574,
        "city" : "Mountain View",
        "postal_code" : "94043",
        "country_code" : "US",
        "country_name" : "United States",
        "continent_code" : "NA",
        "created_date" : ISODate("2017-10-20T14:51:45.176+05:30")
    },
    {
        "ip_address" : "66.249.66.21",
        "latitude" : 37.41919999999999,
        "longitude" : -122.0574,
        "city" : "Mountain View",
        "postal_code" : "94043",
        "country_code" : "US",
        "country_name" : "United States",
        "continent_code" : "NA",
        "created_date" : ISODate("2017-10-24T08:27:24.385+05:30")
    }
],
"urls" : [
    {
        "host" : {
            "time" : ISODate("2017-10-20T14:51:45.197+05:30"),
            "url" : "http://www.indianmobileprices.com/index.php/mobile/info/9-APPLE/7062-APPLE-iPhone+7+/dehradun"
        }
    },
    {
        "host" : {
            "time" : ISODate("2017-10-24T08:27:24.405+05:30"),
            "url" : "http://www.indianmobileprices.com/brand/mobiles/10-LENOVO/bhubaneswar"
        }
    }
],
"created_date" : ISODate("2017-10-24T08:27:24.405+05:30"),
"current_timestamp" : NumberLong("1508491305"),
"traffic" : null,
"traffic_url" : [
    {
        "url" : "",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-10-20T14:51:45.197+05:30")
    },
    {
        "url" : "",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-10-24T08:27:24.314+05:30")
    },
    {
        "url" : "",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-10-24T08:27:24.578+05:30")
    }
],
"returning_user" : NumberLong("1"),
"returninguser" : "yes",
"updated_timestamp" : NumberLong("1508813844"),
"multisession" : NumberLong("2")
```

},

Here is the query i have used.

```
db.audience.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$ip_details.country_name",
    "device_information":{
      "$addToSet":{ 
        "ipaddress":"$ip_details.ip_address",
        "country_name":"$ip_details.country_name",
        "device_name":"$device_details.name",
        "device_type":"$device_details.type",
        "device_os":"$device_details.os",
        "devicen_osversion":"$device_details.os_version"
      }
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  { "$project":{
    "device_information":1,
    "_id":0,
    "countrySize":{ "$size":"$device_information.country_name" },
    "desktopSize":{ "$size":'$device_information.device_type' }
  }},
  { "$match":{ "countrySize":{"$gt":1} }},
  { "$match":{"desktopSize":{"$device_information.device_type":"desktop"} }}
])
```

For that i could not get expected result is given below.need to change query for the result.

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "countrySize" : NumberInt("4"),
    "desktopSize" : NumberInt("2"),
    "device_information" : [
        {
            "country_name" : [
                "Singapore"
            ],
            "device_name" : "generic web browser",
            "device_os" : "Windows",
            "device_type" : "desktop",
            "devicen_osversion" : "10",
            "ipaddress" : [
                "52.220.245.83"
            ]
        },
        {
            "country_name" : [
                "Singapore"
            ],
            "device_name" : "Apple iPhone",
            "device_os" : "iOS",
            "device_type" : "others",
            "devicen_osversion" : "10.3.3",
            "ipaddress" : [
                "185.89.218.227"
            ]
        },
        {
            "country_name" : [
                "Singapore"
            ],
            "device_name" : "generic web browser",
            "device_os" : "Mac OS X",
            "device_type" : "desktop",
            "devicen_osversion" : "10.12.6",
            "ipaddress" : [
                "121.7.242.239"
            ]
        },
        {
            "country_name" : [
                "Singapore"
            ],
            "device_name" : "Samsung Galaxy Note 4",
            "device_os" : "Android",
            "device_type" : "mobile",
            "devicen_osversion" : "6.0.1",
            "ipaddress" : [
                "220.255.108.72"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

I need query for results that is given above.

Comment: Thanks for showing us what you expect to get. Do you think you might consider showing us the original source data where this result is actually meant to come from? Your query is a bit messy and we cannot really work backwards from what you have written and the result alone. So post the source data.

Comment: Please check now. only one record shown to get idea.

Comment: anyone here to help.